# Compilation error on operator overloading when sorting vector

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, operator-overloading, mingw

I have a class roughly defined like below. Among others, it has a `<` comparison operator.

```
class DictionarySearchItem {

public:

    DictionarySearchItem(); 
    double relevance() const;
    bool operator<(const DictionarySearchItem& item) { return relevance() > item.relevance(); }

};

typedef std::vector<DictionarySearchItem> DictionarySearchItemVector;
```

I then use the class this way:

```
DictionarySearchItemVector searchItems;

for (unsigned i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++) {
    // ...
    // ...
    DictionarySearchItem item;
    searchItems.push_back(item);
}
```

However when I try to sort the vector:

```
std::sort(searchItems.begin(), searchItems.end());
```

I'm getting the following compilation error with MinGW.

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:91: erreur : passing 'const hanzi::DictionarySearchItem' as 'this' argument of 'bool hanzi::DictionarySearchItem::operator<(const hanzi::DictionarySearchItem&)' discards qualifiers
```

I don't quite understand what is incorrect with my code and the error message is not clear to me. The same code compiles fine with MSVC2008. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: I got the explanation for this wrong the first time around. I have updated my answer. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the less-than operator `const`:

```
bool operator<(const DictionarySearchItem& item) const { ... }
                                                   ^
```

The reason is probably that `sort` relies on the fact that elements being compared cannot change as a result of the comparison. This can be enforced by having both sides of the `<` comparison be const, which means the operator has to be const, as well as it's argument.

Comment: I don't get the explanation. Shouldn't we be able to call a const method from a non-const method without problems?

Comment: @Hippo yes, of course you can. My bad, I am half asleep today.

Comment: @Hippo well, it means the sort algorithm is passing a `const DictionarySearchItem` on the LHS of the `<` comparison, which requires the operator to be const (the RHS's constness it taken care of because the operator's argument is `const &`). The logic is that sort cannot deal with elements changing when compared, because this would totally break the sorting logic. So both sides of the `<` have to be const (I think this is not explicitly stated in the standard though).